# Как найти наименьшее и наибольшее значение в объектах?

Tags: javascript

Как найти объект, внутри которого находится наименьшее и наибольшее значение `price`?

```
"2018-02": {
    "2018-02-09": {
        "price": 13025
    },
    "2018-02-15": {
        "price": 12499
    }
},
"2018-04": {
    "2018-04-01": {
        "price": 15990
    }
}
```

В итоге должен получиться объект:

```
{
    "max": {
        "price": 15990,
        "month": "2018-04",
        "date": "2018-04-01"
    },
    "min": {
        "price": 12499,
        "month": "2018-02",
        "date": "2018-02-15"
    }
}
```

Изначально планировал сортировать сначала ключи дней каждого месяца, а потом и сами месяцы, но в моей голове заварилась алгоритмическая каша и что-то мне перехотелось писать такую громадину. Есть ли способ попроще?

Comment: чтобы максимум и минимум найти сортировка не нужна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

для нахождения минимального и максимального значения сортировка не нужна, достаточно один раз просмотреть все ключи

```js
var data = { 
  "2018-02": {
    "2018-02-09": {
        "price": 13025
    },
    "2018-02-15": {
        "price": 12499
    }
  },
  "2018-04": {
    "2018-04-01": {
        "price": 15990
    }
  }
};

var min = {price : 999999999999 }, max = {price: 0};
for( m in data ){
  for(d in data[m]){
     let obj = data[m][d];
     
     if(obj.price < min.price){
        min = { month: m,  date: d, price: obj.price };
     }
     if(obj.price > max.price){
        max = { month: m, date: d, price: obj.price };
     }
  }
}

console.log(min, max);
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо, возьму этот способ на вооружение.